# Get empy result from my code with Azure Speech translation API In Python

Tags: python, azure, translation, azure-cognitive-services

When I tried running the following code in my Colab, I got no result - no error as well. Is there any issue with how the blogs are positioned or anything else?  As you can guess I am a greenhorn so I can not find the issue  ;-)

```
import json
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

API_KEY = "2b0ddf64d03744d8aa77c0ca526ecc18"
ENDPOINT = "https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken"

media_file_path = "/content/konec_Outlook.wav"

translation_config = speechsdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(
    subscription=API_KEY, endpoint=ENDPOINT) 
translation_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-GB"
translation_config.add_target_language("cs-CZ")

audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=media_file_path)
recognizer = speechsdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(
    translation_config=translation_config, audio_config=audio_config)

# Initial recognition
result = recognizer.recognize_once()
vars(result)

# Check if the initial recognition was successful
if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.TranslatedSpeech:
    source_language_text = result.text
    duration = result.duration // pow(60, 4)
    print(result.translations['cs-CZ'])

    translation_json = json.loads(result.json)
    print(translation_json['RecognitionStatus'])
    print(translation_json['Duration'])
    print(translation_json['Text'])
    for translated in translation_json['Translation']['Translations']:
        print(translated['Language'])
        print(translated['Text'])
        print()

recognizer = speechsdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(
    translation_config=translation_config, audio_config=audio_config)
outputs = []
toStop = False
while not toStop:
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        toStop = True
        break
    result = recognizer.recognize_once()
    translation_json = json.loads(result.json)
    for translated in translation_json['Translation']['Translations']:        
        print(translated['Language'])
        print(translated['Text'])
        outputs.append({'language': translated['Language'],  'text': translated['Text']})
        
print(outputs)
```

Comment: used this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windows%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-python) [links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/text-sdk-overview?tabs=python)

Comment: add this to void error ```try:
    # Your code here
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))``` make sure to update speech service  ```pip install --upgrade azure-cognitiveservices-speech ```  .proper file path

Comment: Create a Azure Translator [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/create-translator-resource) also

Comment: @Sampath - what are all these comments for? It’s like you’re posting random content here - this is not what comments are for. Also it’s not the place for blocks of code - it’s unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon   These are the responses to the requestor's follow-up comments, however, the requestor deleted his comments. Thank you for your input on the solution drafting; I have added an outline of the code modifications I did in order to fix the attributeError that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to translate the recognized Azure speech from the audio file.

- Using the below Python code with Azure Cognitive Services to recognize and translate speech from an audio file. It detects the language of the recognized speech and then translates it into Czech.

```py
import requests
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

# Load the Azure Cognitive Services key and region for Translator

translator_key = ''
translator_region = ' '
translator_endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com'

# Load the Azure Cognitive Services key and region for Speech
speech_key = ""
speech_region = " "

def detect_language(text, key, region, endpoint):
    path = '/detect'
    url = endpoint + path
    params = {
        'api-version': '3.0'
    }
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': region,
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    body = [{
        'text': text
    }]
    request = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
    response = request.json()
    language = response[0]["language"]
    return language

def translate(text, source_language, target_language, key, region, endpoint):
    url = endpoint + '/translate'
    params = {
        'api-version': '3.0',
        'from': source_language,
        'to': target_language
    }
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': region,
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    body = [{
        'text': text
    }]
    request = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
    response = request.json()
    translation = response[0]["translations"][0]["text"]
    return translation

def recognize_and_translate_speech():
    try:
        # Configure the Speech SDK
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=speech_region)
        speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"

        # Set up the audio configuration to use an audio file
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename="C:/Users/Hello.wav")

        # Create a SpeechRecognizer
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

        # Recognize speech from the audio file
        speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()

        if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            recognized_text = speech_recognition_result.text
            print("Recognized Speech: {}".format(recognized_text))
            
            # Detect the language of the recognized text
            source_language = detect_language(recognized_text, translator_key, translator_region, translator_endpoint)
            print("Detected Language: {}".format(source_language))
            
            # Translate the recognized text to Czech
            target_language = 'cs-CZ'  # Czech
            translated_text = translate(recognized_text, source_language, target_language, translator_key, translator_region, translator_endpoint)
            print("Translated Text (to Czech): {}".format(translated_text))
            
        elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.no_match_details))
        elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
            print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
        
    except speechsdk.SpeechError as e:
        print("Speech SDK error: {}".format(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recognize_and_translate_speech()
```

**Updated code:**

- To handle exceptions, I have added a try and exception block in the below code.

```py
import requests
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

# Load the Azure Cognitive Services key and region for Translator

translator_key = ''
translator_region = ' '
translator_endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com'

# Load the Azure Cognitive Services key and region for Speech
speech_key = ""
speech_region = " "

def detect_language(text, key, region, endpoint):
    path = '/detect'
    url = endpoint + path
    params = {
        'api-version': '3.0'
    }
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': region,
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    body = [{
        'text': text
    }]
    request = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
    response = request.json()
    language = response[0]["language"]
    return language

def translate(text, source_language, target_language, key, region, endpoint):
    url = endpoint + '/translate'
    params = {
        'api-version': '3.0',
        'from': source_language,
        'to': target_language
    }
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': region,
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    body = [{
        'text': text
    }]
    request = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
    response = request.json()
    translation = response[0]["translations"][0]["text"]
    return translation

def recognize_and_translate_speech():
    try:
        # Configure the Speech SDK
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=speech_region)
        speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"

        # Set up the audio configuration to use an audio file
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename="C:/Users/Hello.wav")

        # Create a SpeechRecognizer
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

        # Recognize speech from the audio file
        speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()

        if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            recognized_text = speech_recognition_result.text
            print("Recognized Speech: {}".format(recognized_text))
            
            # Detect the language of the recognized text
            source_language = detect_language(recognized_text, translator_key, translator_region, translator_endpoint)
            print("Detected Language: {}".format(source_language))
            
            # Translate the recognized text to Czech
            target_language = 'cs-CZ'  # Czech
            translated_text = translate(recognized_text, source_language, target_language, translator_key, translator_region, translator_endpoint)
            print("Translated Text (to Czech): {}".format(translated_text))
            
        elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.no_match_details))
        elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
            print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recognize_and_translate_speech()
```

**Output:**

[image]

- For the issue failed to initialize platform (azure-c-shared) install OpenSSL 3.0 for the reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=linux%2Cubuntu%2Cdotnetcli%2Cdotnet%2Cjre%2Cmaven%2Cnodejs%2Cmac%2Cpypi#platform-requirements) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751026/how-to-fix-microsoft-cognitive-speech-error-failed-to-initialize-platform-azur).

Comment: Thank you for help :) I got the following error: "Speech Recognition canceled: CancellationReason.Error
Error details: Runtime error: Failed to initialize platform (azure-c-shared). Error: 2153" It seems that there is some issue with the Azure service, but I did not find any issue there. Do you know where I should look? Thanks a lost! 
"

Comment: @Adam Black please check the `System Environment variable ` , `file path`, `formate of file`  and `pip list` to check package is installed

Comment: This answer doesn’t *answer* anything specific - it’s a block of code, with no explanation of any changes/fixes. Also - why redirect OP to a support forum ? The important thing is to have OP provide all necessary detail (including debugging info) in the question .

Comment: @AdamBlack  For the issue failed to initialize platform (azure-c-shared) install OpenSSL 3.0 for the reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=linux%2Cubuntu%2Cdotnetcli%2Cdotnet%2Cjre%2Cmaven%2Cnodejs%2Cmac%2Cpypi#platform-requirements) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751026/how-to-fix-microsoft-cognitive-speech-error-failed-to-initialize-platform-azur).